# Convert a list of vectors of different lengths to a data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr

Couldn't find any solution to this question online, but apologies if I missed it.

I have a list of several `vector`s (all `character` in this example), of different lengths:

```
ll <- list(f1 = c("a","b","c"),f2 = c("d","e"),f3 = "f")
```

I want to convert it into a `data.frame` that will cover all combinations of the lists elements. So the resulting `data.frame` will be:

```
data.frame(f1 = rep(f1,2), f2 = rep(f2,3), f3 = rep(f3,6))
```

Is there any function that achieves that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expand.grid` should work in this case -

```
expand.grid(ll)

#  f1 f2 f3
#1  a  d  f
#2  b  d  f
#3  c  d  f
#4  a  e  f
#5  b  e  f
#6  c  e  f
```

Another similar alternative would be `purrr::cross_df`.

```
purrr::cross_df(ll)
```